# Can't import Python module even though it is in the PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to run Pixar's USDZ converter tool but i can't seem to run the Python script, it complains with the error `Error: failed to import pxr module. Please add path to USD Python bindings to your PYTHONPATH`.

I am doing this on Ubuntu instead of the native MacOS, but i have compiled from source the USD library, located in `/usr/local/USD/`.

Runnig the script outputs the above error:

```
$ ./usdzconvert -h
  Error: failed to import pxr module. Please add path to USD Python bindings to your PYTHONPATH
```

even though I have added the path to the PYTHONPATH:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/usr/local/USD/lib/python:/usr/local/USD/lib/python/pxr:/usr/local/USD/lib
```

furthermore Python seems to see that just fine:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/home/julien', '/usr/local/USD/lib/python', '/usr/local/USD/lib/python/pxr', '/usr/local/USD/lib', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

I've also tried adding `print(sys.path)` to the begining of the script to confirm it was loading the same env variable and running it i get the same path as above.

The script portion that throws the error is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os.path
from os import chdir
import sys
import importlib
import tempfile
from shutil import rmtree
import zipfile

usdLibLoaded = True
kConvertErrorReturnValue = 2

if sys.version_info.major != 3:
    print('  \033[93mWarning: It is recommended to use Python 3. Current version is ' + str(sys.version_info.major) + '.\033[0m')

try:
    from pxr import *
    import usdUtils
except ImportError:
    print('  \033[91mError: failed to import pxr module. Please add path to USD Python bindings to your PYTHONPATH\033[0m')
    usdLibLoaded = False
```

I don't know anything about python so I am at loss to figure out this import issue, any ideas?

I have python 2 and 3 installed:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.17

python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

but considering the script starts off with a shebang instructing to use python3 i would think this would be fine, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally figured out what the problem was.
I've modified the python script to print the actual import message and this is what I got:

```
dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__tf)
```

A quick google search brought me to this [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/326226/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-pyinit__tf2/) that explains that the module was compiled with python 2, so I recompiled USD with python 3 and re-installed all its corresponding v3 dependencies and then I ran the script again and this time no more import error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known why, but sometimes, something like this worked for me:

```bash
PYTHONPATH=. ./usdzconvert -h
```

How about this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os.path
from os import chdir
import sys
import importlib
import tempfile
from shutil import rmtree
import zipfile

usdLibLoaded = True
kConvertErrorReturnValue = 2

if sys.version_info.major != 3:
    print('  \033[93mWarning: It is recommended to use Python 3. Current version is ' + str(sys.version_info.major) + '.\033[0m')

pxr_path = '/usr/local/USD/lib/python/pxr'
sys.path.append(pxr_path)
sys.path.append(os.path.dirpath(pxr_path))

try:
    from pxr import *
    import usdUtils
except ImportError:
    print('  \033[91mError: failed to import pxr module. Please check the path to USD\033[0m')
    usdLibLoaded = False
```

Comment: this gave the same result

Comment: i get `AttributeError: module 'posixpath' has no attribute 'dirpath'`, changing it to `diname` give the same import error and if i comment that line out i get the import error as well. Seems to me the path is fine but somehow python cant import the lib.

Comment: i think i know what the problem is, i will report back in a bit once i try it out